# stack relative layouts android

Tags: android, android-layout

which layouts would i use / how would i go about stacking layouts ontop of each other without overlap?

I am trying to contain 2 relative layouts inside a linear layout.  The relative layouts needs to be stacked vertically on each other.  I have tried the following code but am not having any luck.  any suggestions?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/headerquickmatch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/matchnameheader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            .../>

        <EditText
            ... />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/matchnameheader" >

        <TextView
            ... />

        <EditText
            ... />

        <Button
            ... />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `android:orientation="vertical"` on your parent linear layout. So all the child layouts(relative layouts) will be stacked vertically automatically. Use different id for each layout component.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/headerquickmatch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    *android:orientation="vertical"*
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/matchnameheader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            .../>

        <EditText
            ... />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/matchnameheader" >

        <TextView
            ... />

        <EditText
            ... />

        <Button
            ... />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

please add **orientation=vertical** in top parent linear layout.so all child layout will show  in stacking layout.

i hope this is useful to you.